# How to map ICollection<Type> to extending class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a data model that looks like this:

```
// Base data item class
public class DataItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    [Required]
    public int DataItemGroupID { get; set; }
    public virtual DataItemGroup DataItemGroup { get; set; }
}

// Extending data item class
public class SpecificDataItem : DataItem
{
    public string ExtraField { get; set; }       
}

// Class for grouping of data items that may be extended or not.
public class DataItemGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public virtual ICollection<DataItem> DataItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExtendedDataItem> ExtendedDataItems { get; set; }
}
```

My issues is that when I use Entity Frameworks lazy loading, DataItemGroup.DataItems is populated with all items, including my ExtendedDataItems, but DataItemGroup.ExtendedDataItems is always empty.

I suspect that I am missing a mapping of some sort, but I don't know what I should be looking for. Any ideas on how to get DataItemGroup to load both the DataItems and ExtendedDataItems collections through lazy loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create just one relationship using the base class (`DataItem`):

```
public class DataItemGroup
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }       
  public virtual ICollection<DataItem> DataItems { get; set; }
}
```

When you need to filter the elements for an specific type that inherit from `DataItem`, you could use [`OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301729(v=vs.110).aspx) method , for example:

```
var dItemGroup= dc.DataItemGroups.FirstOrDefault();
var extendedDataItems=dItemGroup.DataItems.OfType<ExtendedDataItem>();
```

Comment: This worked well. I added a property of public IEnumerable<ExtendedDataItem> ExtendedDataItems { get { return Equipment.OfType<ExtendedDataItem>(); } } as a shortcut. :)